# How can I position my divs within the header without affecting mobile responsiveness

Tags: html, css, mobile, position, responsiveness

I'm new to HTML and CSS, if anyone could help me... I basically have this header that occupies all the width, and two blocks in it (inline-blocks with content). My goal is very simple, I want their position to change (I've made two pics below to demonstrate). But I'm also trying to make it responsive to mobile (I'm using a web resizer that goes 320x586 and up, to variate), and everything else on the website worked, but that didn't.

- Sample how it is right now: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ98I.png)
- Sample what I'm trying to make: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NeBC.png) (in original code, the second block is a picture with stabled by "max-width" property, that make it to be just that size)

But every time I try to adjust the inline-blocks with box elements (margin, padding, etc) it only kinda works, but when I open in mobile resizer, they either are cropped, or overflow the header. If I leave the divs just be themselves with their inline-block standard set, they work in mobile perspective.

I've tried a few things for a few days, I didn't try flex 'cause I haven't learned it yet.  I've tried all the "position" values, but in mobile they don't work.  In my original code, the 2 div inline-blocks have no "width" and "height" values, just "max-width" and "max-height", but the sizes are just like the pictures I put here. I tried using the "overflow" property but it only works vertically, horizontally it still overflows.

Can anyone help me, please? :')

I've made a html/css sample for demonstration:

#### ~~~ EDIT ~~~

I'm adding two new pics after the suggestion from Sarah (thanks!), adding "flex" and "space-around" worked with pc browser size (first pic), but with mobile size it is cropped (pic 2)

- PC BROWSER - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Nwa.png) (the inline-blocks are aligned, as I wanted)
- MOBILE - [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiYZY.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Posicionamento do elemento div</title> 
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        nav {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 30px;
            border: 1px solid black;;
        }
        header {
            min-height: 550px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.582), transparent);
        }
        #um {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 10px solid black;
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: aqua;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #dois {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Início</a>
        <a href="#">Sobre mim</a>
        <a href="#">Habilidades</a>
        <a href="#">Contato</a>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <div id="um"></div>
        <div id="dois"></div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, I do suggest you use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to control the layout. I only needed to add two lines of CSS to the `header` selector. Once you specify `display: flex;` you then use `justify-content: space-around;` to control the spacing horizontally. In this case, space around each `div` will be equally divided.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}


header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-height: 550px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.582), transparent);
}

#um {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#dois {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="um"></div>
  <div id="dois"></div>
</header>
```

For different screen sizes, you can use media queries. Here is an example using a media query for a small screen size or mobile view:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  header {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

This above media query will apply the css that will change the flex-direction until the screen size is greater than 600px.

Comment: Hi @Sarah, thanks so much! (: 
I've done what you suggested me, and it really worked for the web browser size, it's very simple compared to what I was trying to do. But when I change to mobile browser size it keeps getting cropped. Would you have any suggestions to that?

I've uploaded two new pics right above the code, in "~~~EDIT~~~", to show you how it's now

Comment: For smaller screens or mobile, you can use  [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). You can set specific css rules different screen sizes and change flex properties as well. I'll add a small edit to my post so can see how it works

Comment: I didn't even know about media queries, I'll look more into it. It helped a lot, header is totally fixed for now, thanks (: